# ITMSTransporter 'software_screenshots' tag issue

Tags: ios, macos, metadata, itunes, itmstransporter

I'm using `ITMSTransporter` to send xml that updates my app's info in iTunes Connect. I'm having difficulty with software_screenshots tag.

I'm updating existing localization in iTunes Connect (dutch to be exact). That localization has already some info there with defined screenshots.

I **do NOT want to update screenshots**, but if i use xml that doesn't contain   (see below) then all the images in iTunes Connect are wiped out.

Docs says: " Software Screenshots (required on initial delivery of a locale )"

So is it a bug or am i doing something wrong?

```
<package xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" version="software5.1">
    <metadata_token>14075873352</metadata_token>
    <provider>Provider</provider>
    <software>
        <vendor_id>12345</vendor_id>
        <software_metadata>
            <versions>
                <version string="1.0">
                    <locales>
                        <locale name="nl-NL">
                            <keywords>
                                <keyword>dutch1</keyword>
                                <keyword>dutch2</keyword>
                                <keyword>dutch3</keyword>
                            </keywords>
                            <title>Dutch title</title>
                            <description>dutch desc</description>
                            <version_whats_new>dutch</version_whats_new>
                            <support_url>some url</support_url>
                            <privacy_url/>
                        </locale>
                    </locales>
                </version>
            </versions>
        </software_metadata>
    </software>
</package>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation you have to include all description of files in the section:

```
 <software_screenshots>
        <software_screenshot display_target="iOS-3.5-in" position="1">
              <size>11630</size>
              <file_name>pr_source.png</file_name>
              <checksum type="md5">8ccc2a3bb16c4e1c808d5811c0d47b48</checksum>
         </software_screenshot>
....
</software_screenshots>
```

1. If you include new file in this section or change the checksum, then checksum won't be equal and iTunes connect change or add this file in the position defined in  software_screenshot->position. In this way the new files should be in root of folder.
2. If you doesn't define any description of files, then all files will be removed from the store.
3. If you don't want to change any files, you will have to describe these files in this section. But you don't want to include these files in the root of folder. The iTunes connect will ignore this files in this way.

I hope it will help you to solve your problem.